# Python how to call the result of a dictionary and pass the result to a few variables

Tags: python

I have 3 variables x,y,z which will have different values depending on the outcome of 3 tests i am going to perform. So there will 8 possible outcomes of the tests. These 8 outcomes, will match to the corresponding results stored in a dictinary called dic. I will need to pass the corresponding results to the variable x,y,z.

The code as below:

```
fetch = requests.get('http://www.example.com')

match_M = re.search(r'something1...' , fetch.text)
if match_M != None: match_M = 1 
else: match_M = 0

match_K = re.search(r'something2...' , fetch.text)
if match_K != None: match_K = 1 
else: match_K = 0

match_T = re.search(r'something3...' , fetch.text)
if match_T != None: match_T = 1 
else: match_T = 0

outcome = [[0,3,1], [0,2,1,], [0,3,2], [0,2,1], [1,3,1], [1,3,2], [2,3,1], [3,3,1]]

dic = {'111':outcome[0], '110':outcome[1], '101':outcome[2], '100':outcome[3], '011':outcome[4], '010':outcome[5], '001':outcome[6], '000':outcome[7]}

X_num = str(match_M) + str(match_K) + str(match_T)

print dic['X_num']

x, y, z = dic['X_num']
```

Is there a better way to write it where i do not need to use str(match_M) + str(match_K) + str(match_T), maybe I could just use something like dic['match_M+match_K+match_K']

Sorry if this sound too stupid, I am just starting to learn.

Comment: If the code already works and you just want help improving it, [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate site than StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, @skrrgwasme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would be an improvement?

```
fetch = requests.get('http://www.example.com')

match_M = 0 if re.search(r'something1...' , fetch.text) else 4
match_K = 0 if re.search(r'something2...' , fetch.text) else 2
match_T = 0 if re.search(r'something3...' , fetch.text) else 1

index = match_M + match_K + match_T

outcomes = [[0,3,1], [0,2,1], [0,3,2], [0,2,1], [1,3,1], [1,3,2], [2,3,1], [3,3,1]]

x, y, z = outcomes[index]
```

This is based on the observation that you're building up a 3-digit binary number, so the digits are in the 4s place, the 2s place, and the 1s place. I reversed 1s and 0s from your scheme, since that way the "outcomes" are in the same order as the binary numbers you're building up.

**EDIT**

A little "code golf" (sorry):

```
fetch = requests.get('http://www.example.com')

x, y, z = [[0,3,1], [0,2,1], [0,3,2], [0,2,1], [1,3,1], [1,3,2], [2,3,1], [3,3,1]][
    sum(2**i * (0 if re.search(pattern, fetch.text) else 1)
        for i, pattern in enumerate([r'something3', r'something2', r'something1']))]
```

Comment: i think `outcomes[index]` instead of `dic[index]` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! @smarx. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably approach the problem a bit differently, at least for the three below lines

```
outcome = [[0,3,1], [0,2,1,], [0,3,2], [0,2,1], [1,3,1], [1,3,2], [2,3,1], [3,3,1]]  
dic = {'111':outcome[0], '110':outcome[1], '101':outcome[2], '100':outcome[3], '011':outcome[4], '010':outcome[5], '001':outcome[6], '000':outcome[7]}
X_num = str(match_M) + str(match_K) + str(match_T)
```

I would prefer to iterate over outcome and Cartesian products of the cardinality sets of [0, 1 ] and index it with each separate match variables

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> dic = {k : v for k, v in zip(product([0,1], repeat = len(keys)), outcome)}
>>> dic
{(0, 1, 1): [0, 2, 1], (1, 1, 0): [2, 3, 1], (1, 0, 0): [1, 3, 1], (0, 0, 1): [0, 2, 1], (1, 0, 1): [1, 3, 2], (0, 0, 0): [0, 3, 1], (0, 1, 0): [0, 3, 2], (1, 1, 1): [3, 3, 1]}
>>> dic[(match_M, match_K, match_T)]
[1, 3, 2]
```

I would even extend the idea and discourage you to use separate match variables, but rather a match tuple

```
keys = [r'something1...', r'something2...', r'something3...']
match = [[0, 1][re.search(key , fetch.text) != None] for key in keys]
```

To Summarize

```
def foo(url, keys, outcome):
    from itertools import product, izip
    fetch = fetch = requests.get(url)
    match = [[0, 1][re.search(key , fetch.text) != None] for key in keys]
    dic = {k : v for k, v in izip(product([0,1], repeat = len(keys)), outcome)}
    return dic[match]
```

This will help you to scale the design and not restrict based on the cardinality of the keys

**Note** I generally prefer `[0, 1][re.search(key , fetch.text) != None]` but there alternate syntax of like `0 if re.search(key , fetch.text) == None else 1` is equally encouraged

Comment: Thank you very much for helping Abhijit, but for my current level, I really need more time and practice to understand your code. Thanks anyway! Great work.